# Subsample after GroupBy

Tags: python, pandas, twitter

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
df =

id   tweet 
1     a         
1     b        
1     b        
1     a        
2     d         
2     a         
2     a         
3     b      
3     b   
4     a       
4     b
```

Now I want to group by their id and get their tweets:

```
df.groupby(["id"]).count()
```

Which leads me to

```
df =

id   count
1     4         
2     3        
3     2     
4     2
```

However, I'd like to subsample the data so that only users with `<n` tweets are saved in the dataframe and if you have more than `n` samples (tweets) your tweets should get randomly subsampled. How do I do this? I haved tried the following but they only return `n` samples for the entire row...

```
n=3
print(data.groupby(["user_id"]).apply(lambda x: x.sample(min(n,len(x)), replace=False)).reset_index(drop=True))
print(data.groupby('user_id').sample(n, random_state=1))
```

Comment: What do you mean by "randomly subsampled"?

Answer (score 1):

shuffle then `groupby().head()`:

```
df.sample(frac=1).groupby('id').head(N)
```